# Elastic search : Uneven number of nodes in each availability zones

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elastic search cluster with 28 nodes spread across 3 Availability zones. While 2 of them are having 11 nodes each one is having 6 nodes. Shard count is almost same in almost all the nodes in all availability zones. Will there be any performance issue due to this ? Also how ES is making sure equal number of shards available in each node ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main role of **availability** zones is to ensure... [high **availability**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.5/high-availability-cluster-design-large-clusters.html#high-availability-cluster-design-three-zones).

This means that if one zone completely goes down, you have a full copy of your data in your other zone(s) provided you have configured [shard allocation awareness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.5/modules-cluster.html#shard-allocation-awareness). If two zones have 11 nodes and the third one has 6 nodes, it is highly unlikely that the third zone has a significant copy of all your data, because more data will sit on the two 11-nodes zones than on the 6-node one.

So, your cluster is probably running fine, but in case of failure of either or both of the 11-node zone, you might suffer data loss and/or cluster imbalance.